# Edit this function to return the most recent files path

Tags: javascript

I tried and have looked at StackOverflow and the other posts are not answering my questions. This is a unique question. How can I edit to have the path of the most recently uploaded file returned from the getMostRecent() function and saved to the lastdownloadedimage variable?

```
var pathtocheck = "C:\Users\user1\Downloads";


var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');


var getMostRecent = function (dir, cb) {
    var dir = path.resolve(dir);
    var files = fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
        var sorted = files.map(function(v) {
            var filepath = path.resolve(dir, v);
            return {
                name:v,
                time:fs.statSync(filepath).mtime.getTime()
            }; 
        })
        .sort(function(a, b) { return b.time - a.time; })
        .map(function(v) { return v.name; });

        if (sorted.length > 0) {
            
            cb(null, sorted[0]);
    
        } else {
            cb('Y U NO have files in this dir?');
        

        }
    })
}

await getMostRecent(pathtocheck, function (err, recent) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log(recent);

});

var lastdownloadedimage = ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `lastdownloadedimage` before the call to `await getMostRecent(...)`, and change the value of `lastdownloadedimage` once the call to `getMostRecent()` returns:

```
var lastdownloadedimage;

await getMostRecent(pathtocheck, function (err, recent) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    lastdownloadedimage = recent;
    console.log(recent);
});
```

Comment: Gives error.  

 var sorted = files.map(function(v) {
                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @RobomanRobo Have you tried adding `console.log(err)` just before that line?